# Point custom Domain to the google cloud function through global https loadbalancer with serverless NEG as backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-functions, custom-domain

I had a running `myfunctionname` cloud function with HTTP trigger URL:

For Ex- `https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/myfunctionname`

Now I want to map this cloud function URL to public domain URL

For Ex- `https://my-domain.com/path`

Public domain URL is setup in DNS to point to loadbalancer. Global external https loadbalancer is created with host, path rules & backend service

> Host: `my-domain.com` , Path Rule: `/path` , Backend Service: `Serverless NEG pointing to myfunctionname cloud function`

Now if I hit the API endpoint with the Cloud Function Http trigger URL, API response is 200 OK, it's working

> `GET` Request on endpoint `https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/myfunctionname/show/jobs`

But when I hit the API endpoint with the custom domain URL:

> `GET` Request on endpoint `https://my-domain.com/path/show/jobs`

> **API error response is 404 Not Found. Cannot GET /myfunctionnameshow/jobs**

Can someone please point out the issue why my custom domain URL is not redirected to cloud function URL? Actually my expectation is hitting `https://my-domain.com/path/show/jobs` API endpoint should be equivalent to hitting `https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/myfunctionname/show/jobs` API endpoint.

Comment: Nope. Since you added `/path` path rule, then the LB is calling the function as `https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/myfunctionname/path/show/jobs`

Comment: @FerreginaPelona How can I configure so that /path should not come in the calling of the function?
Expected: `/path ----> https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/myfunctionname/show/jobs`